# Why `journalctl --list-boots` doesn't match what `uptime` and `who -b` report?

Tags: boot, systemd, reboot, systemd-journald, journalctl

Here's a test script I used:

```bsh
last_reboot=$(last reboot | grep 'still running' | awk '{for (i=5; i<=NF; i++) printf $i FS}' | awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF - 2; i++) printf $i FS}')
if [ "$last_reboot" ]; then
    date -d "$last_reboot" '+last reboot: %Y-%m-%d'
fi

days=$(uptime | awk '{print $3}')
hours=$(uptime | awk '{print $5}' | sed -E 's/,$//')
h=$(echo "$hours" | cut -d: -f 1)
m=$(echo "$hours" | cut -d: -f 2)
date -d "- $days days - $h hours - $m minutes" '+uptime: %Y-%m-%d'

who -b | awk '{print "who: " $3}'

journalctl --list-boots | awk '$1 == "0" {print "journalctl: " $4}'
```

Locally, all four dates match.

I ran it on about 10 servers. `last reboot` doesn't report anything (probably, because `wtmp` gets rotated by `logrotate`). `uptime` and `who -b` match. And `journalctl` doesn't. What exactly does `journalctl --list-boots` report? Why can it not match what other tools report?

Comment: systemd collates and stores information reported by syslog

Comment: Maybe you can use **tuptime**, it is designed exactly for track and report the system life.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The new binary logs on Linux operating systems do not work in the way that the old binary logs did.

The old binary logs were `/var/log/wtmp` and `/var/log/btmp`.  At system bootstrap an entry would be written to `wtmp` with the username `reboot`, and at shutdown an entry would be written to `wtmp` with the username `shutdown`.  Finding the times that the system was rebooted was a matter of using the `last reboot` and `last shutdown` commands to print out these entries.

The new binary logs are the systemd journal, and they do not have such entries.

Instead, *every journal record* has a field named the *boot ID*.  You can see this with the `-o verbose` option to `journalctl`.  A boot ID is generated by the kernel at bootstrap, and `systemd-journald` applies the current boot ID, taken from the kernel, to every log record as it is adding it to the journal.

To implement the `list-boots` functionality, `journalctl` scans the *entire journal*, reading the timestamps and boot IDs of *every record*, and noting *the earliest and latest timestamps* associated with each unique boot ID.

Thus if parts of the journal are purged, or conversely stick around overlong, the apparent boot and shutdown times reported by `journalctl` will differ wildly from the actual boot and shutdown times.

`/run/utmp` is a table of terminal login records, with special entries for bootup and shutdown.  These entries are read by `uptime` and `who -b`.  They are written by programs such as `systemd-update-utmp`, an analogue of the FreeBSD `utx` command, which are run as parts of the startup and shutdown procedures.  They are not run first or last, as the relevant services are not (and indeed cannot be) ordered absolutely first or last.  There may be journal entries with the relevant boot ID that precede the time that `systemd-update-utmp reboot` is run, and similar journal entries that postdate the time that `systemd-update-utmp shutdown` is run.

## Further reading

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/383575/5132
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/294206/5132

Comment: Can you elaborate on "stick around overlong" part? "Thus if parts of the journal are purged, or conversely stick around overlong, the apparent boot and shutdown times reported by journalctl will differ wildly from the actual boot and shutdown times." How can it affect boot and shutdown times reported by `journalctl`?

Comment: Read the very first item of further reading.

Comment: I'd already done so, when I was asking my question. Let me try and explain my point. When logs doesn't get purged, we get more or less accurate boot and shutdown times. Since at those moments something is bound to get to the log. When some parts of the log get purged, boot and shutdown times change. Could you possibly mean this particular thing? That depending on how much of the log you have, boot and shutdown times may differ drastically? If that wasn't your point, I'd appreciate it to hear at least a brief explanation.

Comment: @x-yuri My reading of what he said agrees with this statement of yours: "depending on how much of the log you have, boot and shutdown times may differ drastically?" and I think he said it pretty clearly.