# Debian - two entries in `last reboot` in `still running`

Tags: debian, last

What can be a reason for `last -x reboot` showing two last entries as `still running`? Besides, I'm pretty sure I did not reboot this server December, 16, though it could be something with power on hosting provider. If that was the case, would this be expected result?

```
root@cthulhu-new ~ # last -x reboot
reboot   system boot  4.13.0-0.bpo.1-a Sat Dec 16 06:26   still running
reboot   system boot  4.13.0-0.bpo.1-a Thu Dec  7 07:56   still running
reboot   system boot  4.13.0-0.bpo.1-a Wed Dec  6 11:10 - 07:55  (20:44)

wtmp begins Tue Dec  5 19:59:27 2017
```

Here's the output of `last -x shutdown` which has no entry for Dec 16:

```
root@cthulhu-new ~ # last -x shutdown
shutdown system down  4.13.0-0.bpo.1-a Thu Dec  7 07:55 - 07:56  (00:00)
shutdown system down  4.13.0-0.bpo.1-a Wed Dec  6 11:10 - 11:10  (00:00)

wtmp begins Tue Dec  5 19:59:27 2017
```

Comment: This is not actually a systemd question.  These are the old binary logs.  See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/408936/ for a systemd question.

Comment: Give a try to `tuptime -t`. It have a clear output.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, it would be the expected result. `last` doesn’t know that your system was shut down on December 16, presumably because it wasn’t an orderly shut down (power loss or something like that). Because [of the way it displays boots](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/410734/86440), it considers that the last two boots are still running.

Things will sort themselves out to some extent the next time the system is shut down; `last` will then use the new shut down time for both December 7 and 16 boots.