# What is the correct way for a script-based service to log messages with priorities to its own systemd log?

Tags: linux, shell-script, systemd, logs, systemd-journald

I have a shell script that I run as a systemd service, and I want to log messages [with granular priorities](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/logger.1.html#FACILITIES_AND_LEVELS) into the systemd log for that service.

When I use `logger(1)`, journald only logs some of the messages and discards the rest. Which message ends up getting logged to the service log appears to be completely random; Sometimes only one or two messages get logged, sometimes no message gets logged at all.

At first I thought it was a boot order/dependency issue, but that doesn't seem to be the case because all messages do appear in the system log (i.e. `journalctl --system`) but not the service log (i.e. `journalctl -u SERVICE.service`). I also tried `systemd-cat` but its behavior was unfortunately similar.

What is the correct way for a script-based service to log messages with priorities to its own systemd log?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem that systemd has with `logger` is the same problem that it has with its own `systemd-notify` tool.
The protocol is datagram-based and asynchronous, and the tools do one job.
The invoker forks a process to run the tool; it fires off a datagram and forgets about it; and the process exits.

`systemd` server processes for the logging and readiness notification protocols want to know what service the sender belongs to, the former in order to add the right service name field to the log entry and the latter in order to know what service is being talked about.
They get the process ID of the datagram sender from Linux, and then they go to the process table to look up what control groups the process belongs to, and hence what service it belongs to.

If the sending process has done its job and immediately exited, this does not work (subject to a race condition).
The process is no longer in the process table.
`systemd-notify` notifications fail; `logger` information does not get marked as belonging to the relevant service.
Switching to a stream protocol (e.g. with `logger`'s `--tcp` option) wouldn't fix this *unless* the logging protocol itself were *also* altered so that the client awaited a response from the server before closing the stream and exiting, which it does not.
RFC 5426 has no server acknowledgements sent back to clients.

So although the log information is in the journal, it isn't tagged with the service name and isn't pulled out when you query by service name.
(These aren't separate logs as you think, by the way.
`journalctl` is simply applying filters to one big log.
`-u` is a filter.)

This is a long-standing, widely-known, bug.

The `systemd` people describe this as a deficiency of Linux.
It doesn't have proper job objects that can be used to encapsulate and track sets of processes; nor does its `AF_LOCAL` datagram socket mechanism transport such information.
If it did, `systemd` could put all service processes into a job, and its logging and readiness notification servers could pull out the client-end job information whenever they receive a datagram, even if the client process had since exited.

There is an idiosyncratic protocol specific to `system-journald`, that some versions of `logger` even speak.
No, `_SYSTEMD_UNIT` is a "trusted field" set at the server end, and attempts by clients to set it will be ignored; and that's a datagram-based, asynchronous, protocol without acknowledgements too.
It has exactly the same problem.

To reliably have log entries tagged with the right service, *write to standard error*.
That's long-lived and more reliably connectable to the service unit name at the server end.
Yes, you cannot specify the old facilities and priorities; that's the trade-off that you have to make.

## Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2015). "[using a synchronous protocol when pulling client credentials](http://jdebp.uk./FGA/unix-daemon-readiness-protocol-problems.html#SynchronousProtocol)" *Readiness protocol problems with Unix dæmons*.  Frequently Given Answers.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2016). *[Linux control groups are not jobs](http://jdebp.uk./FGA/linux-control-groups-are-not-jobs.html)*.  Frequently Given Answers.
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/383575/5132
- Davide Lima Daum (2017-02-23).  *[Journalctl miss to show logs from unit](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1426152)*.  RedHat bug #1426152.
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/294206/5132

Comment: Thank you so much for this thorough response. It helped me figure out a way to get `journald` to bin my messages correctly. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/598966/353063

Answer (score 0):

With @JdeBP's extremely helpful answer, I was able to find a way to get my messages to appear in the correct service log: Since the problem stems from the race condition between `journald` and whatever is reaping `logger`, you could have an long-living intermediary datagram relay for each script/service. That way, `journald` will always find the sending process.

The following function launches a `socat` relay if it hasn't been launched yet, then sets `logger` to send messages to the relay socket instead of the default. When the parent script exits, the relay is automatically terminated and its socket removed.

```
# Usage:  builtin_logger  TAG SEVERITY MESSAGE
builtin_logger() {
    if [[ "${SHELL_SERVICE_LOG_SOCK-}" == "" ]]; then
        declare -g SHELL_SERVICE_LOG_SOCK
        SHELL_SERVICE_LOG_SOCK="/tmp/service-log.$$"
        sh -c "socat UNIX-RECV:'$SHELL_SERVICE_LOG_SOCK' UNIX-SENDTO:'/dev/log' &
               SOCAT_PID=\$!
               trap \"if [ -e '$SHELL_SERVICE_LOG_SOCK' ]; then rm '$SHELL_SERVICE_LOG_SOCK'; kill \$SOCAT_PID; fi\" EXIT INT TERM
               tail --pid=$$ -f /dev/null" & 
        sleep 0.1 # waiting for socat to run (TODO inotify)
    fi
    logger -u "$SHELL_SERVICE_LOG_SOCK" -t "$1" -p user."$2" "$3"
}
```